# Entering Vietnam with two passports issued by the same country and the exit stamp from the previous country is in the other passport

Tags: visas, passports, vietnam

I'm a non-dual citizen of Hungary with two passports, both issued by Hungary. I'm currently in Malaysia. I entered Malaysia on passport B but my Vietnam visa is issued for passport A.

My exit stamp from Malaysia will be in passport B. Will they check the exit stamp at the Vietnam border? If so, can I run into problems if I show it in another passport (again, it's issued by the same country)?

I heard some countries are strict about this and don't understand multiple passports from the same country. Note that I did disclose my second passport in the visa application.

Does anybody have an experience with this?

Comment: Seems unlikely that Vietnam is concerned about Malaysia’s border controls.

Comment: Some countries check exit stamps from the previous country. So they just might be. I'm not sure about the situation in Vietnam, though.

Comment: What if someone comes from a country that doesn't stamp passports, or stamp only the entry? (Argentina, Australia, Israel, UK, USA)